# calling growlnotify from inside cygwin from inside ruby

Tags: ruby, cygwin, growl

I'm having some trouble with calling growlnotify from within a ruby script running on cygwin on a Windows 7 machine. I suspect this is doable but there are a few too many layers of interpretation happening and I can't figure out what the right escape sequence needs to be.

The following code (with no custom icon specified) is working fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

l = "Hello World"

system("/cygdrive/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/Growl\\ for\\ Windows/growlnotify /t:testedfa  \'#{l}\'")
```

However, when I try to specify an icon things start to fail. Depending on how many layers of escape characters I try, the command will either do nothing at all or growlnotify will crash. Specifically with the code shown below, I get no response from Growl at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

l = "Hello World"

system("/cygdrive/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/Growl\\ for\\ Windows/growlnotify /t:testedfa /i:C:\\\workspace\\\tryCPUnit\\\amp\\\testedfa\\\pass.png \\\'#{l}\\
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the multi-argument form of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441), that will remove one layer of escaping by bypassing the shell. Something like this:

```
system(
    '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Growl for Windows/growlnotify',
    '/t:testedfa',
    '/i:C:/workspace/tryCPUnit/amp/testedfa/pass.png',
    l
)
```

Windows generally accepts forward or backward slashes so I cleaned up your `/i` switch a bit, go back to `\\` if it doesn't like that path.

Using the single argument `system` is almost always just a bug waiting to happen, I wouldn't use it unless there was no other way (and I can't think of when there wouldn't be a better way ATM).

Comment: Ah! So much cleaner and it works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Denis: Yeah, all the escaped escapes are somewhat unsightly :)